# Flask Jinja2 URL with url_for() not working

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I've run into a problem, where the data passed to my template from the route is in the form of a list of tuples. This format is necessary, I believe, because I need both a unique ID and a person's name, which is not unique, and I must sort the names alphabetically. The list of tuples, sorted, achieves that perfectly.

This throws an error, "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'item' is undefined":

```
<ul>
{% for item in student_list %}
    <li><a href="{{ url_for( 'student', idnum=item[0] ) }}">{{ item[1] }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This does NOT throw an error, and works perfectly:

```
<ul>
{% for item in student_list %}
    <li><a href="/student/{{ item[0] }}">{{ item[1] }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So I've resorted to the second version, but I would like to use the url_for() function if possible.

This is the route:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    all_students = get_all_students(PEOPLE)
    return render_template('index.html', student_list=all_students)
```

This is the format of the list:

```
student_list = [('896-95-9224', 'Jimenez'), ('778-73-1993', 'Ramos'), ('578-92-7338', 'Thomas'), ('003-73-8821', 'Watts')]
```

[Repo here](https://github.com/macloo/python-beginners/tree/master/flask/part3_templates/ex3-app)

There are a number of answered questions in SO about Flask/Jinja2 URL building, but none specifically address this case, where a list or tuple index is needed.